# amcharts adding legand with the dynamic text

Tags: javascript, html, legend, amcharts

I am using amcharts for rendering the data in column charts, I need the legand to be shown along with the text of the each 'valueField'.

I am trying something like this :

```
"legend": {"horizontalGap": 10,
    "maxColumns": 1,
    "position": "right",
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10,
    "marginTop": 10,
    "labelText":"[[value]]"
}
```

[My JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NawazSE/z1r7fq2d/2/)

It's showing the different colors well, but the text is not getting displayed.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the title of the graphs so that the legend knows what to use to replace the `labelText` of each legend, which defaults to `[[title]]`:

https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#labelText

It looks like the `labelText` will **not** parse any other special placeholders like `[[value]]` other than `[[title]]`.

So the fix is, just to remove what you have set as the label text in the legend section (just leave it as default), and add titles on each graph:

```
legend: {
    ...,
    // "labelText": "[[value]]"
},
...,
graphs: [
    {
        id: "g1",
        fillAlphas: .9,
        title: "value 1",
        ...
    },
    {
        id: "g2",
        fillAlphas: .9,
        title: "OR WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DISPLAY",
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

**fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/fm7jLkta/